# Conditional statement just to display login text

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hi guys am just trying to display in my breadcrumbs login or register depending on the page the user is on.

So if the user is on my login page it shows login and if the user is on register page it shows register

I tried using route help function i.e

```
@if( Route::has('login') )
<H2> login </h2>
@endif
```

It doesn't work any ideas please

Comment: Do you have a named route called `login`? see the list `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yes I do, I obviously have auth

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@if($request->routeIs('login')) 
    <h1>Login</h1>
@endif
```

Here 'login' is route name, this method works with named route.

[Read More](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)

Comment: It says undefined request

Comment: use request() instead of $request

Comment: Now the error I have is method illuminate\http\request::routeIs does not exist

Answer (score 0):

$routeName= \Request::route()->getName();

Comment: Do I use this with the if statement

Comment: @if($routeName=="login"){ }